# How to call controller action method from middleware on .NET 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

The project was written on .NET Core 2.2 and this design worked:

```cs
public static void ProcessFileStorageRequest(this HttpRequest request, string path)
{
    path = path.TrimEnd(new[] { '/' });
    request.Path = "/productfile/download";
    string encodedPath = UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(path);
    request.QueryString = new QueryString($"?path={encodedPath}");
}
```

Now the download method is not called. Url changes from `https://localhost:5000/path/download.html` to this `https://localhost:5000/path/file.exe/?path=path%2Ffile.exe`

request changes, I'm attaching a screenshot from the debug:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wln5n.png)

Comment: Check old working project and see what files are in the bin folder.  Often people manually put files into the folder to get project working.  It looks like the path variable is empty so code looks for files in same location where the executable is found.  Code could be failing because a file is missing in the executable folder.  You are not getting compiler errors, just runtime errors.

Comment: @jdweng, path variable is not empty. Now I have old branch in git with project on net core 2.2. I change branch and this code works

Comment: Can you please show a [mre]? When `ProcessFileStorageRequest` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void ProcessFileStorageRequest(this HttpContext context, string path, EndpointDataSource endpointDataSource)
{
    var endpoint = endpointDataSource.Endpoints.FirstOrDefault(e =>
    {
                var descriptor = e.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();

                return descriptor != null
                       && "download".Equals(descriptor.ActionName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                       && "productfile".Equals(descriptor.ControllerName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    });

    if (endpoint == null)
    {
                throw new Exception("No valid endpoint found.");
    }

    context.SetEndpoint(endpoint);
}
```

The *EndpointDataSource* adds from DI.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure configure the middleware before `app.UseRouting();` like below:

```
app.UseMiddleware<YourMiddleware>();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

A simple demo you could follow:

```
public class CustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        Extension.ProcessFileStorageRequest(context. Request, "/file.exe");
        await next(context);
    }

}
public static class Extension
{
    public static void ProcessFileStorageRequest(this HttpRequest request, string path)
    {
        path = path.TrimEnd(new[] { '/' });
        request.Path = "/home/Privacy";
        string encodedPath = UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(path);
        request.QueryString = new QueryString($"?path={encodedPath}");
    }
}
```